# Adding Public or Private members to class gives various Run-time errors

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17, bad-alloc

So for some reason, when trying to add a 'stack' variable to a class (public or private) in this multi-class project, it will give a run-time error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

or

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  deque::_M_new_elements_at_front
```

or

```
Segmentation fault (Core Dumped)
```

This depends on the type of stack I try to add, it seems.

I commented out all of the methods (in the .cpp and the .h) except for the constructor, and the things I'm trying to add aren't referenced anywhere, but it always gives an error. The odd thing is, I already have a stack that works fine, stored as public, I simply can't add any more.

From Main.cpp:

```
int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    Scanner funScanner = Scanner(argv[1]);
    DatalogProgram funProgram = DatalogProgram(funScanner.tokenize());

}
```

From my DatalogProgram.h file:

```
class DatalogProgram
{
    public:
        DatalogProgram(stack <Token> tokensFromScanner);
        stack <Token> tokenStack; //<-- this one seems to work fine



    private:
        stack <Predicate> schemes;
        stack <Predicate> facts;
        stack <Rule> rules;        //These 4 stacks are based on other classes, but even the int stack gives a similar error
        stack <Predicate> queries;
        stack <int> testStack; //<-- this stack also gives a run-time error
};
```

Any ideas why it might be doing this?

UPDATE: I've been running my project file through a makefile, so I tried running it without it, and I got another error,

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct NULL not valid
```

Upon searching that error, it looks like there must be a string set to a null pointer, so I'm currently looking for that.

Comment: You get the [`bad_alloc` exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) when you run out of memory. And the `length_error` exception could be because you add to many elements to the stack. All in all it indicates that you either have a *lot* of data, or you have some large loops, or invalid loop conditions making then in effect infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't see how I could get the length_error thing when I never actually access the stack though?

Comment: What is `argv[1]`?

Comment: why would you tokenize argv[1]? imagine a cmdline call `my_prog verbose param1`, this will end in argv[0] = "my_prog", argv[1] = "verbose", argv[2] = "param1". Tokenizing this may result in a single token (depending on your tokenizing logic)

Comment: quite off-topic: why are you using a stack for things like string-tokens?

Comment: Are your classes like `Predicate` and `Rule` polymorph (do you store objects of a child-class of `Predicate` or `Rule` in the stack?